# How does conversion constructor work in this case?

Tags: c++

How does conversion constructor work?

Does the compiler creates a temporary object of myClass and uses the constructor myClass(int i) initialize the temporary object first and then pass the object to function output?

OR

Does the compiler directly initializes the output() parameter rhs using the
myClass(int i) constructor.

quite confused with the flow of the conversion constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class myClass
{
public:

   myClass(int i)
   {
      a = i;

   }

   int getA() const
   {
      return a;
   }

private:
   int a;
};


void output(const myClass& rhs)
{
    cout << "rhs.getA(): " << rhs.getA() << endl;
}

int main()
{
   output(120);
}
```

Comment: afaik the former, you get a temporary that gets bound to the const ref, in fact if you removed const i suspect you would get an error saying a temporary cannot be bound to a non const ref.

Comment: How do you expect "a temporary object of myClass" to use "the constructor myClass(int i)"? You have a "temporary object of myClass", as a starting point. How do you expect to use that together with "the constructor myClass(int i)", in some form or fashion? Your question is unclear.

Comment: It's so obvious that I don't know how to answer. Of course, the object is required, thus it must be created, temporary, prvalue.

Comment: In your example, a temporary must be constructed - using the constructor that accepts an `int` - before it can be passed to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is a reference. A reference is not an object. It must be bound to some object instead and the type of the object must be compatible with the type of the reference.

So yes, a temporary object to which the reference can bind must be created. This temporary object is initialized by a call to the `myClass(int i)` constructor with `120` as argument.

This is also why the program won't compile if you remove the `const` in `void output(const myClass& rhs)`. Binding a non-`const` lvalue reference to a temporary is generally not allowed.